# "incompatible types" при использовании setSelectionModel()

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

Есть строки кода:

```
private JList jlResultsList;
```

И в конструкторе:

```
jlResultsList = new JList(arraySearchResult);
jlResultsList.setSelectionModel(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

IDE отмечает как ошибку `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`.

А при попытке компиляции выдает:

> Error:(49, 59) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to javax.swing.ListSelectionModel

`import javax.swing.*;` прописан. В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть так:

```
jlResultsList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Метод [setSelectionMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setSelectionMode-int-) принимает значение `int`, одно из трёх:

- `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`
- `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`
- `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`

В то время как метод [setSelectionModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectionModel--) принимает [ListSelectionModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html). Так как передавать `int` вместо `ListSelectionModel` некорректно, то и возникает ошибка.